# cnn model after bert

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, bert-language-model

I try get output from last hidden state of bert model and pass it through CNN MOdel

```
class MixModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,pre_trained='distilbert-base-uncased'):
        super().__init__()        
        self.bert =  AutoModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
        self.hidden_size = self.bert.config.hidden_size
        self.conv = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=256, kernel_size=5, padding='valid', stride=1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size= 256- 5 + 1)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.clf = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size*2,6)
        
      
           
    def forward(self,inputs, mask , labels):
        
        cls_hs = self.bert(input_ids=inputs,attention_mask=mask, return_dict= False) 
        x=cls_hs
       # x = torch.cat(cls_hs[0]) # x= [416, 64, 768]
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.clf(x)
        
        
      
        return x
```

I got this error
TypeError: conv1d() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (tuple, Parameter, Parameter, tuple, str, tuple, int), but expected one of:

- (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
  didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!tuple!, !Parameter!, !Parameter!, !tuple!, !str!, !tuple!, int)
- (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, str padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
  didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!tuple!, !Parameter!, !Parameter!, !tuple!, str, !tuple!, int)

Comment: print the type of `cls_hs` that `self.bert` returns - I suspect you'll find it is a tuple and not a tensor as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def __init__(self,pre_trained='distilbert-base-uncased'):
        super().__init__()        
        self.bert =  AutoModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
        self.hidden_size = self.bert.config.hidden_size
        self.conv = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=768, out_channels=256, kernel_size=5, padding='valid', stride=1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size= 256- 5 + 1)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.clf1 = nn.Linear(256,256)
        self.clf2 = nn.Linear(256,6)
```

also before `x = self.conv(x)` use `permute(0,2,1)`
in_channel=the output from transformer(768)
out_channel=up to you(number of filters)